# Erro ao usar métodos para gerar hash e pegar MAC address

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, hash

[De acordo com essa minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41827/seguran%C3%A7a-com-chave-em-asp-net-mvc), na resposta do Cigano para se fazer o *hash* do *mac address* da placa de rede basta usar dois métodos.

Mas na forma de se usar eles para recuperar o dado e fazer a verificação estou tendo um erro:

> A field initializer cannot reference that non-static field, method, or propety

Lembrando aqui que a forma de se usar é: 
      `var chave = GetSHA1HashData(GetMacAddress());`

Será que alguém pode me ajudar ?

Aqui os métodos em questão pra facilitar:

```
  public class AutenticacaoController : Controller
    {
    private EntidadesContexto db;
    string chave = GetSHA1HashData(GetMacAddress());

    public AutenticacaoController()
    {
        db = new EntidadesContexto();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (db != null) db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    // GET: Autenticacao
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(String Login, String Senha)
    {
        //verificando login pelo usuario do banco de dados ...
        Usuario login = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Login == Login && x.Senha == Senha).FirstOrDefault();
        if (login != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Nome.ToString(), false);
            Session.Add(".PermissionCookie", login.Perfil);
            Session.Add("UsuarioID", login.UsuarioID);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //pagina padrao para todos os usuarios...
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
    public ActionResult Sair()
    {

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Remove(".PermissionCookie");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //Aqui são métodos para pegar o endereço MAC da placa de rede do computador e a considerá-la como chave de licença
    private string GetSHA1HashData(string data)
    {
        SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();

        byte[] hashData = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data));

        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hashData.Length; i++)
        {
            returnValue.Append(hashData[i].ToString());
        }

        return returnValue.ToString();
    }

    private string GetMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddresses = string.Empty;

        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return macAddresses;
    }
    //Aqui termina
```

Comment: Não sei o que você está fazendo, onde está dando esse erro. Forneça informações que ajudem responder.

Comment: Feito @bigown... E esta dando errona hora de usar eles: var chave = GetSHA1HashData(GetMacAddress());. Que no caso é string e não var.

Comment: Você pode mandar o código da classe completa?

Comment: @GuilhermePortela feito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vai funcionar da maneira que está. Você não pode criar uma variável inicializada na classe preenchida por métodos da mesma classe. Na prática, é como se o compilador não conhecesse os métodos.

Tem duas maneiras de resolver:

## 1. Chamando os métodos dentro de outro método

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(String Login, String Senha)
{
    string chave = GetSHA1HashData(GetMacAddress());

    ...
}
```

## 2. Encapsulando os métodos em classes estáticas

```
public static class GeradorDeLicencas
{
    public static string GetSHA1HashData(string data) { ... }
    public static string GetMacAddress() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Causa

A variável chave é declarada a nível de classe, e portanto, é um campo. Os campos não podem inicializados (declarados e definidos ao mesmo tempo) com um valor não-estático, método ou propriedade. Você precisa declará-lo a nível de classe, e defini-lo no construtor.

### Por que?

Um campo só pode ser inicializado com membros estáticos, uma vez que a instância não é definida até o construtor ser executado, e a inicialização direta acontece antes de qualquer construtor ser executado.