# Gerar hash de endereço MAC e guardar no banco de dados

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, hash

[De acordo com essa minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41827/seguran%C3%A7a-com-chave-em-asp-net-mvc) para pegar o endereço *mac* da placa de rede e gerar o hash dele, usa-se os seguinte métodos:

```
private string GetSHA1HashData(string data)
    {
        SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();

        byte[] hashData = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data));

        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hashData.Length; i++)
        {
            returnValue.Append(hashData[i].ToString());
        }

        return returnValue.ToString();
    }

    private string GetMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddresses = string.Empty;

        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return macAddresses;
    }
```

Mas como que eu faço pra guardar esse hash no banco de dados ?
Lembrando aqui que já tenho o *model* feito e a tabela já criada:

```
public class Chave
{
    [Key]
    public string EnderecoMacRede { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Você vai usar uma tabela separada para guardar o endereço? Em que momento do uso do sistema você deve pegar os dados e inseri-los?

Comment: Exato. Assim que a aplicação já *startar* a primeira vez já guarda o *hash*. E nas vezes subsequentes só vai fazer a verificação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É importante você não deixar essa informação fácil pra alguém que esteja tentando quebrar seu sistema, então essa denominação não é uma boa.

Altere para o seguinte:

```
public class Licenca
{
    [Key]
    public string Chave { get; set; }
}
```

A maneira correta é usar uma *Migration* pra gerar a informação de chave pra você. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SeuProjeto.Models.SeuProjetoContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(SeuProjeto.Models.SeuProjetoContext context)
        {
            // Estou supondo que você implementou os métodos dentro de uma classe
            // estática, então ficaria:
            var chave = LicencasHelper.GerarLicenca();

            context.Licencas.AddOrUpdate(
                l => l.Chave,
                new Licenca
                {
                    Chave = chave
                });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

A classe `LicencasHelper` seria algo como:

```
public static class LicencasHelper
{
    public static string GerarLicenca() 
    {
        return GetSHA1HashData(GetMacAddress());
    }

    private static string GetSHA1HashData(string data)
    {
        SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();

        byte[] hashData = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data));

        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hashData.Length; i++)
        {
            returnValue.Append(hashData[i].ToString());
        }

        return returnValue.ToString();
    }

    private static string GetMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddresses = string.Empty;

        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return macAddresses;
    }
}
```

Nas publicações subsequentes, considere comentar o código da *Migration* a fim de se evitar que o mesmo seja explorado por engenharia reversa.

Outra coisa que pode ser feita é separar o código do *Helper* em uma DLL só para ele, e remover a referência quando a *Migration* for realizada, mas isso apenas se você não precisar conferir a licença no login.

Em todo caso, uma `Action` de login ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
public ActionResult Login() 
{
    var licenca = context.Licencas.FirstOrDefault();

    if (licenca == null) return View("SemLicenca");

    if (licenca.Chave != LicencasHelper.GerarLicenca()) return View("LicencaInvalida");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Agora ficou bem mais claro Cigano. Mas, como posso salvar esse *hash* uma vez somente, e assim que aplicação iniciar e como posso fazer essa verificação no meu *controller* e não deixar passar da página de login por exemplo ? Já que o *hash* não vai estar presente.

Comment: Bom, a Migration garante esse salvamento único. Como você vai conferir o hash sempre, então `LicencasHelper` não pode sair do código. Na `Action` de Login, você traz a Hash do banco, chama `LicencasHelper` novamente e compara os dois hashes. Se forem iguais, você deixa logar. Caso contrário, exibe uma View dizendo que a licença não está de acordo.

Comment: Sera que poderia colocar essa sugestão na resposta também ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Feito.

Comment: Muito bom ! Vou implementar aqui e te aviso !

Comment: Funcionoooou !!