# Ao criptografar uma string com SHA1 não retorna o valor esperado

Tags: c#

Estou consumindo um *webservice* de *nfse* (nota fiscal de serviço eletrônica), e a função de recepção do lote de nfse, existe que a senha esteja criptografada usando o algorítimo **SHA1**.

O Manual exemplifica assim:

A senha: "1234", deve ficar assim: cRDtpNCeBiql5KOQsKVyrA0sAiA=

Cheguei a usar o código abaixo:

```
public string SenhaHash(senha){
   var hash = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
   var senhaBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(senha);
   var senhaHash = hash.ComputeHash(senhaBytes );

   return senhaHash;
}
```

Porem o valor retornado é um array de byte, que não tem nada a ver com o valor que devo chegar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Segurança com chave em asp.net mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41827/seguran%c3%a7a-com-chave-em-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `cRDtpNCeBiql5KOQsKVyrA0sAiA=` é um base64 do resultado do SHA-1.

---

Infelizmente não posso lhe ajudar com o código exato. Mas se você possui o *array de byte* do SHA-1, basta codificar este resultado para Base64. [Fiz um exemplo disso, em outra linguagem, para que talvez ajude.](https://play.golang.org/p/HhB_-REJF4d)

Se o SHA-1 estiver correto o Base64 do resultado do SHA-1 terá que dar o `cRDtpNCeBiql5KOQsKVyrA0sAiA=`. Aparentemente poderá usar o [`Convert.ToBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx), para converter para a codificação correta.

O Algoritimo correto ficaria assim:

```
public string SenhaHash(senha){
  var hash = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
  var senhaBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(senha);
  var senhaHash = hash.ComputeHash(senhaBytes );
  var senhaHashBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(senhaHash);

  return senhaHash;
}
```

Comment: Consegui, deu certo, vou editar a sua resposta para mostrar como ficou o meu código com a sua solução.